# An exception in Json.NET: Token PropertyName in state "Start" would result in an invalid JavaScript object

Tags: json, json.net

I see the error in my prod server log; can u give me any hint about what kinds of situations would trigger the error? Thanks.

```
Token PropertyName in state Start would result in an invalid JavaScript object.

2010-08-02 04:33:56,446 DEBUG 10 XXX - at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.AutoComplete(JsonToken tokenBeingWritten)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.WritePropertyName(String name)
```

Comment: Could you post the fields and properties of the classes being serialized?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source:

http://json.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/64750#128137

It would appear you are trying to write something out-of-order.

Without seeing your code it would be difficult to know what.

Possibly some exception is being caught and thrown and upsetting the output order?